# Concatenate mysql query in php where quotation marks are closed

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query where I have to close the quotation marks in order to give the user id session. But at the end I want to put LIMIT 1 but I cant beacause the quotation marks are already close.

//query I have in my php file

```
"SELECT * from grouptitle where userid=".$_SESSION['userid'];
```

//query i want to have ( the quotation mark closes after iduser

```
"SELECT * from grouptitle where iduser=".$_SESSION['iduser'] LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

`"SELECT * from grouptitle where iduser={$_SESSION['iduser']} LIMIT 1"`

OR

`"SELECT * from grouptitle where iduser=".$_SESSION['iduser']." LIMIT 1"`

Comment: @jose Did this Solve your issue? If yes Please mark this answer as Accepted.

Comment: Thanks very much :)